# Can JavaScript be made "invisible" to the client?

Tags: javascript

To my understanding, most of what you get when you are downloading a desktop application is binary code, code that has already been compiled (unless the application requires your pc to have an X interpreter installed). Can't we do something similar with JavaScript, in a way that the user can't *trivially*
modify the intended interactivity of the site?

I know this isn't possible because of how the web, and browsers work. Your browser requests a site, the site responds with a `.js` file (that is actually stored somewhere in your PC and can be viewed through browser tools, *or your file explorer* ), and the browser's JavaScript interpreter executes it and *nowadays* even compiles it, I think.
But couldn't the inner workings of the browser be modified in a way that, for instance, the server sends you "compiled" JavaScript? Or perhaps sends you the JS files encrypted, the browser then compiles them and makes the uncompiled code inaccessible through the developer's console (and site's source)?

**Is this theoretically possible, if changes were made to the way the web and web browsers work?** I can think of some drawbacks of this, such as, you don't know what the hell you're downloading really (but most users don't know, in general, either way), and it'd break some of the openness of the Web, but it could also make applications potentially more secure, couldn't it?

Comment: You are looking for "javascript obfuscator". Which make the code difficult to parse for human. Encrypting it do not solve the issue for motivated reverse engineering as you have to provide the code for decrypting the javascript. A combination of minification and obfuscation is usually enough to discourage normal users.

Comment: Well, I've read on obfuscators, and I know that they don't really hide anything, like you said, anyone with enough motivation can de-obfuscate it. What I'm asking is more like a theoretical posibility, as in, can it be done by the people who develop the browsers in the first place?

Comment: As you said with, with enough motivation, there is no way to protect your code, as it travel trough the network and browser even end decrypting it in memory space, one could rip the decryption routing of the browser and write a standalone program to decrypt your data to a file. As some of the most popular browser are open-source and that web protocols are open.

Comment: The browser could refuse to let you see the code, but why would it? People would just use a browser that doesn't do that. Depending on how much control you have over the system, you could try to make your browser the only option people have, but people would promptly start reverse engineering your system and dumping RAM and intercepting the network traffic and pursuing all sorts of other avenues to get at what you're hiding.

Comment: The reason it's more difficult to reverse-engineer desktop applications is because the structured of the machine-readable code (machine code) is different than the structure of the human-readable code (a source language such as C). With JavaScript in a browser they're the same, so even if you optimize/compile and obfuscate the code as much as you can, a lot of the original structure will still be there to understand. The entire JavaScript runtime is optimized around this premise; deliberately having a compile re-structure your code would negatively affect performance.

Comment: You could write code that runs in the browser with C, and compile it to JavaScript using Emscripten, or write it using Clojure/ClojureScript. That would be more difficult to reverse-engineer because the the human-readable code was in a different language with a different structure. Or you could compile for something like [native client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client), which is much more like a conventional desktop application. However, these both have significant tradeoffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is "No."  Long answer is "Noooooooooo."

Kidding aside, what you are proposing is called "obfuscation" and would not be any more secure than what exists now.

For example, lets assume that the Javascript was encrypted.  How would the browsers decrypt it?  They would need the key, right?  So the un-encrypted code would be available in the browser's memory when the browser was executing it.  This merely raises the bar for someone who was trying to access the code.

Granted, more people may be discouraged from accessing the code, but this should not be confused with being "more secure".

Comment: Pretty much this. At the end of the day, when you physically give an executable to someone, if they want it enough, they can reverse engineer it. We can make it more difficult or annoying, but it can't really be stopped. If we want to hide business secrets, it should be done on servers we control, with only the end results being sent to the client.

Comment: But to my understanding, reverse engineering already compiled code would be a REALLY complicated issue, wouldn't it? And if JavaScript is already in memory, then it'd surely be in a compiled state? (After being decrypted with the key and executed). Or this might sound very dumb, but couldn't it be compiled server side and then be sent to the browser?
I realize that it's best to keep the dangerous logic on the server side, and that eventually anything can be hacked, it was just a thought... and I'm in no way a computer expert, just an amateur... ha.

Comment: No problem, this site exists for people like all of us.  Yes, it is complicated to reverse engineer code.  The Javascript code can exist in memory in a variety of states, one of which is compiled, yes.  However, you seem to be confusing the concepts of "difficult to access or reverse engineer" vs. "secure".   You're talking about security, but meaning that you want to make it annoying for people to reverse engineer your code.  Your proposals will make it more annoying, but will not make it more secure.

Comment: @Leonarth The "already compiled" code is difficult thing to define in the case of JavaScript. Browser engines might compile the code several different times, in different modes (for compiling/execution speed tradeoffs) during the execution of a single page. A common compilation format for all browsers, let alone all versions of browsers, is a big ask. Also, many optimizations the engines perform require enough knowledge of the original code structure that it would be quite easy to decompile. Browser vendors *could* try to mitigate these issues, but it would be a lot of work, & isn't a priority

Comment: Really interesting answers in here (and in the comments, everywhere!). So in a nutshell, it can be probably done, but there's no reason to and there's not much of a benefit to it. After all, even machine code is "open source" code in a way, isn't it? Ha. Like you say, just harder and more annoying to understand and modify. And to implement stuff like this to the way browsers work would just be... pretty much a waste of time, not make anything any more secure and very complex, requiring a sort of consensus amongst many browser vendors, standards, etc. Alright, that was a big nutshell.

Comment: Yup, you've got it now.

Answer (score 1):

javascript bundling and minification can to some extent secure or make the javascript code less readable to end user.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes.

In fact, [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_Media_Extensions) introduce a similar concept, but for media elements:

> Encrypted Media Extensions (EME) is a W3C draft specification for
>   providing a communication channel between web browsers and Digital
>   Rights Management agent software.
>
> EME has been highly controversial within the W3C, because it places a
>   necessarily proprietary, closed component into what might otherwise be
>   an entirely open and free software ecosystem.

Hopefully, W3C won't be so mad to do the same for arbitrary JavaScript code.